# Formatting Footnotes

Tags: support, formatting

Please excuse my ignorance, but I was wondering if anyone can tell me how to format a footnote when writing an answer or question (Please find an example [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106118/torah-based-on-mesopotamian-and-other-sources/118052#118052)).

I am aware how to do a dividing line at the bottom but haven't yet worked out how to make a smaller 'superscript' style number.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated as I feel it will enhance the presentation of my questions and answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The superscript is done with `<sup>insert number</sup>` which renders as <sup>insert number</sup>.

(For future reference, if you have an example post where a particular format was used, you can use the edit function on that post to see the underlying formatting.)

Thanks to (I think) Isaac Moses who was the one that showed me how to do this when I was getting started here.

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: And the corresponding <sub>subscript</sub>

Comment: Note this is a hack. SE by design does not support footnoting in posts.